# How can I replace every characters in a txt file for another one using Windows Batch Scripting?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a test.txt with a lot of characters. However, I need to replace all of . to /. How can I do this? I tried using the follow code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\HOME\Desktop"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\HOME\Desktop"
SET "filename=%sourcedir%\test.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

(
FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%filename%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "line=!line:.=/!"
 ECHO !line!
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: Did you got any error ?

Comment: I execute my .cmd file , the prompt is shown and close quickly and my outfile.txt is generated empty.

Comment: I see no problem with the batch. Insert a pause in front of the goto :eof or run the batch from an open cmd window to view any error messages. The dot in your replacement is missing

Comment: Check your paths are there correct in your case ?

Comment: Are you sure the input file is ASCII, and not Unicode? FOR /F cannot read Unicode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)